# Front End development framework for IOT dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, web-frontend

We need to build elegant UI for an IOT based web app. It will be a multi-page application with data continuously being pumped to the APIs from our wireless devices.

We are thinking to go with Django for the backend API software but not able to decide what to choose for Front end development. We have considered the widely supported options such as AngularJS and React but not able to figure out what will be best suitable for our case. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of the open source frameworks you can use :

1. [Freeboard.io](http://freeboard.io/) ( Dashboard for IOT)
2. [Total JS](https://www.totaljs.com/dashboard/)
3. [Cyclotron.io](http://www.cyclotron.io/)
4. [Tipboard](http://allegro.tech/tipboard/)
5. [EON](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/)

Answer (score 0):

React and angular can do pretty much the same things for you. Your question should be what tool, library to use to create the dashboard. I think that if you want some simple charts try [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) which is a free open source library. There various other tools as well but most are not free.

Back to the topic of angular vs react. It makes no real difference. Try to develop in whatever you feel more comfortable and want to learn.

Comment: The dashboard part will be needing charts along with several other things. Apart from this, it will still be having all the basic entities of a web app such as static pages, HTML forms, etc. I found that the learning curve of AngularJS as compared to that of React is quite steep, that's why I needed some insight on this.